# How to reduce the vertical space between the widgets in gridview Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to reduce the vertical space between the widgets in a gridview? What do the crossaxisspacing and the mainaxisspacing actually do here? I tried playing around with them but still I am unable to clearly grasp their use.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10,

    children: componentsList.map((value){
      return value;
    }).toList(),

  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `GridView` scrolls vertically, the main axis is the vertical axis. So the `mainAxisSpacing` would be the vertical spacing of the elements and the `crossAxisSpacing` would be the horizontal spacing of the elements.

And to avoid confusions, remember that all the items of the `GridView` will have the same height, if you want to change the size you need to set the [aspectRatio](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AspectRatio-class.html).